# hypernym for clients, suppliers, partners, public enterprises, employees

Tags: word-choice, business-language, hypernyms

I need an abstraction for the above terms for using in a financial service application.

I am thinking to use **"Current Accounts"**.

Is it appropriate to use this term to cover all of these terms that I mentioned on title?

Comment: Your clients and employees might balk at being called *current accounts*. Calling your *partner* that doesn't sound particularly endearing either.

Comment: I don't want to use stakeholder even though was addressed  in some resources. @Lawrence

Comment: If you're not really looking for a hypernym, it depends on the particular abstraction you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Parties**

> 3.
>   a person or people forming one side in an agreement or dispute.
>
> "a contract between two parties"
>
> - informal
>
>   a person, especially one with specified characteristics.

(GOOG)

These are all entities to which you have an agreement, and is normally used in a legal context as a hypernym for a person or collection or persons, such as a corporation. Most of your examples appear to be either persons or corporations.